# Change Sub to Function then Call in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a password generator Sub, I want to change it to a Function and the use it in a Macro to generate a column starting on B2 were each cell after is a unique password.

The only thing it does is delete my B1 Header cell.

Thanks

I have the Sub:

```
Sub RandomPassword()
 Dim i As Integer

  For i = 1 To 8
    If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
        strPassword = Chr(Int((122 - 48 + 1) * Rnd + 48)) & strPassword
    Else
        strPassword = Int((9 * Rnd) + 1) & strPassword
    End If
 Next i
 MsgBox strPassword
End Sub
```

My Atempt and turning it in to a Function:

```
Function RandomPassword(strPassword As String) As String
 Dim i As Integer

 For i = 1 To 8
    If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
        strPassword = Chr(Int((122 - 48 + 1) * Rnd + 48)) & strPassword
    Else
        strPassword = Int((9 * Rnd) + 1) & strPassword
    End If
 Next i
End Function
```

My Calling it:

```
Sub qqq()

    Dim rng As range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With Sheets("sheet1")
        lastRow = .range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").range("B2:B" & lastRow)
        rng.Value = RandomPassword(rng.Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the value of `strPassword` variable to function `RandomPassword`

```
Function RandomPassword(ByVal strPassword As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 8
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            strPassword = Chr(Int((122 - 48 + 1) * Rnd + 48)) & strPassword
        Else
            strPassword = Int((9 * Rnd) + 1) & strPassword
        End If
    Next i

    RandomPassword = strPassword
End Function
```

Also in below procedure you are getting the last used row in `column B` and then overwriting them with random password. I feel like it you need to get the last used row of `column A` instead.

```
Sub qqq()

    Dim rng As range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With Sheets("sheet1")
        lastRow = .range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").range("B2:B" & lastRow)
        rng.Value = RandomPassword(rng.Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Santosh that got me part way there.  The sub is filling at `cell B1 and only coping to cell B2`, I need it to `start at B2 and go to last data cell` can you see how to fix this part?

Comment: @Tim Kindly refresh to get updated code. let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: @Tim  I'm glad I could help. I see you are keen to learn things and  i appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

You need an extra row in your function, just before `End Function`:

```
RandomPassword=strPassword
```

Otherwise your function will have no value, resulting in empty cell.

Comment: Thank you for the response Juri.  Tim