# Split a String at a Specific Word and Create a New Row

Tags: excel, vba, function

I'm trying to split this string at the word "material_cd" and have it create a new row with the split string.

```
material_cd = 10798259 AND inputportcount  24 material_cd = 10798259 AND outputportcount  144 material_cd = 10798259 AND inputblockcount  1 material_cd = 10798259 AND outputblockcount  1 material_cd = 10798259 AND bv_type_name  FDH material_cd = 10798259 AND manufacturer  Corning material_cd = 10798259 AND partnumber  N/A material_cd = 10798259 AND bv_status  Preliminary Designed material CD = 10798259 AND bv_tail_length  25
```

Desired Outcome:

```
material_cd = 10798259 AND inputportcount <> 24
material_cd = 10798259 AND outputportcount <> 144
material_cd = 10798259 AND inputblockcount <> 1
material_cd = 10798259 AND outputportcount <> 1
```

....and so on

Is this possible?

Comment: `SPLIT` retunrs an array, so you can say `a=split(strInput,"material_cd")` then this array a, you can put in a range, so something like `range("a1").resize(ubound(a)-1,1).value=a`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this,

```
Sub tt()

Dim s As String
Dim a() As String

s = "material_cd = 10798259 AND inputportcount  24 material_cd = 10798259 AND outputportcount  144 material_cd = 10798259 AND inputblockcount  1 material_cd = 10798259 AND outputblockcount  1 material_cd = 10798259 AND bv_type_name  FDH material_cd = 10798259 AND manufacturer  Corning material_cd = 10798259 AND partnumber  N/A material_cd = 10798259 AND bv_status  Preliminary Designed material CD = 10798259 AND bv_tail_length  25"
s = Replace(s, "material_cd", "*^*material_cd")
a = Split(s, "*^*")

Range("a1").Resize(UBound(a) - 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(a)

End Sub
```

Comment: How would I turn this into a function?I have numerous strings like the one mentioned above, I need to be able to set a cell to the variable "s" in your sub routine, so as it goes down the lists of cells it uses that string to split.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638449/change-sub-to-function-then-call-in-vba   If you haven't searched yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `split`-command and use the string `material_cd` as split criteria. When working on the splitted parts, add the string `material_cd` again:

```
Const s = "material_cd = 10798259 AND inputportcount  24 ..."
Const splitString = "material_cd"

Dim a() As String, i As Integer
a = Split(s, splitString )

For i = 0 To UBound(a)
    Debug.Print splitString  & a(i)
Next i
```

Comment: Would this be done using the built in VBA interface inside excel?

Comment: I don't get your question. This is VBA code - just put it in a function or subroutine and adapt it to your needs

Comment: Use this the same way I would call the "Concatenation" function in excel? I'd pick a cell, type =Concatenation(.....), or can I make custom functions?